# how to calculate Primes

Tags: c, function, recursion, primes

I want all Primes and the program works but I get a warning:

`warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }`

I know that I need a last `return` in `bool isprim` but I don't get it.

```
bool isPrim(int prim, int tester) {
    if (prim <= 1) {
        return 0;   
    } else if (tester == 1) {
        return 1;   
    } else if (tester >= 1 && (prim % tester) != 0) {
        isPrim(prim, tester - 1);
    } else if ((prim % tester) == 0) {
        return 0;   
    }
}   
    
int main() {
    int eingabe;
    int zaehler = 1;
    printf("Bitte Zahl zum testen eingeben\n");
    scanf("%i", &eingabe);

    if (isPrim(eingabe, eingabe - 1)) {
        printf("Ihre Zahl ist eine Primzahl\n");
    } else {
        printf("Ihre Zahl ist keine Primzahl\n");
    }
    //show me all Primes <1000
    printf("Nun werden alle Primzahlen bis 10000 ausgegeben\n\n");
    while (zaehler <= 10000) {
        if (isPrim(zaehler, zaehler - 1)) {
            printf("%i\t", zaehler);    
        }   

        zaehler++;  
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing a return statement `return isPrim(prim,tester-1);`

Comment: nope i get the warning

Comment: You should tag the language you're working in to get the question visible to the relevant people. It's possible your language doesn't convert integers to booleans implicitly, so you should change `1`s to `true`s and `0`s to `false`s.

Comment: sorry, its "C" your solution doesnt work i get the warning

Comment: Please delete your answer and edit the question. You should read some instructions on how to participate on this site, or take a look at how others do.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't have any branches that might not return a boolean, even if they will never be executed:

```
// This will throw a warning.
bool func(){
  if( true ){
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Either change the last `else if` to an `else`, or add an additional `else` (or just return) in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler emits the warning because there are paths of execution where the function does not have a `return` statement.

- For example, when the function calls itself recursively, the value of `isPrim(prim, tester - 1)` is not returned and no `return` statement is encountered.
- The function has redundant tests, but does not handle all cases: for example if `prim = 2` and `tester = -3`, all tests in the function will evaluate to false and control will *fall off the end* of the function body without a `return` statement.

Here is a modified version:

```
bool isPrim(int prim, int tester) {
    if (prim <= 1 || tester < 1) {
        return 0;   
    } else if (tester == 1) {
        return 1;   
    } else if (prim % tester != 0) {
        return isPrim(prim, tester - 1);
    } else {
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

It can be simplified<sup>1</sup> with the same inefficient semantics as:

```
bool isPrim(int prim, int tester) {
    return (prim <= 1 || tester < 1) ? 0 : (tester == 1) ? 1 :
           (prim % tester != 0) ? isPrim(prim, tester - 1) : 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> this *simplified* alternative has a single statement but is not necessarily simpler to read :)

Answer (score -1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    primeTester1(600851475143)
}

func primeTester1(x int64) {
    cn := true
    var i int64
    for i = 2; i <= int64(math.Sqrt(float64(x))); i++ {
        if x%i == 0 {
            cn = false
            fmt.Printf("%v is not a Prime number as, it is a multiple of %v", x, i)
            break
        }
    }
    if cn {
        fmt.Printf("%v is a Prime number", x)
    }
}
```

Comment: My eyes may be not like they used to be, but this doesn't look like C, and doesn't address the warning question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).